# Why is the FirebaseAuthException not returning the correct code

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a register page where I am trying to allow the user to register but the problem comes when I try to use an email that is already is in use, in the debug console I am getting the following:

```
flutter: Error creating user: [firebase_auth/email-already-in-use] The email address is already in use by another account.
```

But when I try to catch that code in an if else statement it just isn't working I can't see any of my print statements :

```
  Future register() async {
    if (passwordController.text == confirmpasswordController.text &&
        EmailValidator.validate(emailController.text) &&
        passwordController.text.length >= 8) {
      try {
        await dbhandler.createUserAndCollectionInFirestore(
          email: emailController.text.trim(),
          password: passwordController.text.trim(),
        );
        print('I can See This');
      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
        print('cant see this');
        if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
          print('The account already exists for that email.');
        } else {
          print('Some other error');
        }
      }
    } else {
      setState(() {
        regfail = true;
      });
    }
  }
```

the function being called:

```
  // Function to create a new user using FirebaseAuth and create a collection for the user in Firestore
  Future<void> createUserAndCollectionInFirestore(
      {required String email, required String password}) async {
    try {
      UserCredential userCredential =
          await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email,
        password: password,
      );

      String? fcmtoken = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();

      // User created successfully, now create a Firestore collection for the user
      User? user = userCredential.user;

      if (user != null) {
        await createCollectionForUser(user.uid, user.email!);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error creating user: $e');
      // Handle the error as needed
    }
  }
```

Comment: I guess `dbhandler.createUserAndCollectionInFirestore` is your own function. How do you handle errors there? Can you add the code of this function to your question?

Comment: my apologies I have added the missing function

Comment: So the problem is that `FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword` throws the `FirebaseAuthException` but your own function does not. So either handle `FirebaseAuthException` in your `createUserAndCollectionInFirestore` function or (re)throw the exception back to the `register` function.

Comment: What @PeterKoltai said is absolutely correct. To make it simple, just add a `rethrow` statement after `print('Error creating user: $e');`.

Comment: The Rethrow worked but can you please explain to me and anyone reading why it did?